# Concatenate lists with LINQ

Tags: c#

Is it possible to concatenate a `List<List<T>>` into a `List<T>` with a single operation in a way which isn't horrible slow, i.e:

```
List<List<int>> listOfLists = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> concatenatedList = listOfLists.Something...
```

?

Comment: This is called flattening, not concatenation.

Comment: Actually, it IS called concatenation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353462.aspx.

Comment: To flatten a list of lists, you can concatenate them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
listOfLists.SelectMany( l => l );
```

full line:

```
List<int> concatenatedList = listOfLists.SelectMany( l => l ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
listOfLists.Aggregate(new int[0], (res, list) => res.Concat(list));
```