# Joining multiple List<string[]> into a new list

Tags: c#

How could I achieve joining four lists below of different sizes into a single new list. I really don't know how to even tackle this.If I did I would of attempted to post some attempt.

Edit: I should point out the list i am trying to create is not a list of lists per se but rather a list of all the combined lists strings.

```
List<string[5]> coords_list
List<string[8]> outer_plf_list
List<string[8]> planet_start_plf_list
List<string[5]> planet_plf_list
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493858/elegant-way-to-combine-multiple-collections-of-elements or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734556/concatenate-lists-with-linq.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thanks for the links.

Comment: @RyanWalkowski so, what you want is one, single, `List<string>` is it? Or is it `List<string[]>`

Comment: @Ian Pardon? I dont quite follow

Comment: @RyanWalkowski I edited my comment. :)

Comment: @Ian Yeah I am not after a list of lists. Instead, I am trying to combine the lists so essentially I have a single list of all the strings I'm assuming that's the point Bogey was making and your edited answer at the bottom. I had failed to think about it

Comment: @RyanWalkowski OK, noted. Just to clear up some ambiguity. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, try to use `LINQ Concat`:

This resulting in `List<string[]>`

```
var newlist = coords_list
    .Concat(outer_plf_list)
    .Concat(planet_start_plf_list)
    .Concat(planet_plf_list)
```

Or if you need `List<string>` instead, do this:

```
var newlist = coords_list
    .Concat(outer_plf_list)
    .Concat(planet_start_plf_list)
    .Concat(planet_plf_list)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

You could also use `AddRange` as an alternative:

```
var newlist = new List<string[]>();
newlist.AddRange(coords_list);
newlist.AddRange(outer_plf_list);
newlist.AddRange(planet_start_plf_list);
newlist.AddRange(planet_plf_list);
```

And if you have `List<List<List<string>>>` instead of `List<string[]>` with different `string[]` sizes, you could use `SelectMany` to flatten `List<List<List<string>>>` into `List<List<string>>`

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I've clearly gotten mixed up. I had found concat before but i was ending up with List<string[]> when i was trying to get List<string> i didnt notice the difference

Comment: @RyanWalkowski OK, no problem. That's what I wanted to clarify also.. ;) check also Rogey's answer. I think he noticed that too...

Answer (score 3):

Do you want a list of string arrays, or just one big list of strings?

For the first case, lan's solution works.

For the latter, use SelectMany;

```
        List<string[]> p1 = new List<string[]>();
        p1.Add(new String[] { "a", "b" });

        List<string[]> p2 = new List<string[]>();
        p2.Add(new String[] { "c", "d" });
        p2.Add(new String[] { "e", "f" });

        // will contain 6 string items: a, b, c, d, e, f
        var result = p1.Concat(p2).SelectMany(s => s).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Comment: I see that you noticed that too. Voted up. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `AddRange()` method of Lists, like so:

```
var combinedList = new List<string>();
combinedList.AddRange(coords_list);
combinedList.AddRange(outer_plf_list);
combinedList.AddRange(planet_start_plf_list);
combinedList.AddRange(planet_plf_list);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!